# SQL Azure Schema Issue

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm getting an email regarding a Schema Issue on my SQL Azure Database and it reads something like this:

> "Invalid column name 'False'" Error code : 207

**However it doesn't appear to have any more information** and I wouldn't even know where to start because the schema was created before I started in the project, but I suspect this is coming from a Stored Procedure or View.

This is all being reported in Azure Portal, but I have no idea how to proceed. Is there any other way to get the suggestions on Azure Portal in SSMS? I already tried Tuning Advisor and I got an error that SQL Azure was not supported.

[image: Pic of Portal]

Comment: can you please paste entire message ?

Comment: I'd go further: Can you please edit your question to show something related to your schema or data? We can't see *anything*. Also - I'm guessing you might have issues with a column name of `False` - since that's a reserved, unless you properly bracket the name.

Comment: TheGameiswar - That **is** the entire message. The nature of the question is how can I find more about it.

David - I know it's a reserved work and that's why it's throwing the error. The question would be on how to find where it is.

Answer (score 2):

I use this query to to search objects in this scenario.  This will find every occurrence of `false` and should help you find the offending column.  This will find every occurrence of whatever you define `@searchName` as.

I found this on [Pinal Dave's blog](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/06/sql-server-query-to-find-column-from-all-tables-of-database/), way back.  This works in Azure SQL.

```
declare @searchName varchar(50) = 'false'
select  @searchName as SearchName,
        OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(OBJECT_ID) + '.' +  OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) as ObjectName,
        [definition]
from sys.sql_modules
where definition LIKE '%' + @searchName + '%'
order by OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(OBJECT_ID) + '.' +  OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID)
```