# Proper rename table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

In sql server there is stored procedure `sp_rename` that allows to rename tables, databases, columns, etc. Suppose I have table `SomeTable` and stored procedure using this table:

```
create procedure get_temp
as
begin 
    select *
    from SomeTable      
end
```

and if I execute the following code:

```
sp_rename 'SomeTable', 'SomeTable2'
```

my table is renamed. But its old name 'SomeTable' is kept in procedure and if I try to execute procedure, I failed. Is there a way to rename table (column, database, etc) properly with renaming its name in stored procedures and functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there's not. You can create a synonym or a view in order to keep backwards compatibility.

Comment: @Pupkin [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-synonym-transact-sql) For instance `CREATE SYNONYM MyProduct FOR AdventureWorks2012.Production.Product;` by executing this, an object (synonym) will be created and you can query your old table name to query data. It's like an additional name for a table.

Answer (score 3):

Other than the answer offered by Evaldas, there is at least one third party tool that can assist with that sort of operation.

SQLPrompt by redgate has a feature called [Smart Rename](https://documentation.red-gate.com/display/SP7/Renaming+objects) which can generate a script to rename an object and update all of the references to it with the new name.

From SQL Prompt 7 documentation:

> SQL Prompt can create a script that allows you to rename objects in your database without breaking dependencies. You can rename the following:
>
> - Tables (including columns)
> - Views (including columns)
> - Stored procedures (including parameters)
> - Functions (including parameters)
>
> When an object is renamed:
>
> - SQL Prompt also modifies any objects that reference, or are referenced by, the renamed object to ensure that dependency links are not broken.
>
> If you have previously renamed an object using SQL Server Management Studio or Enterprise Manager Rename, or the T-SQL sp_rename command, the object definition will contain the original name.
>
> Any objects that reference this original name are not updated.
>
> To help you locate objects that reference objects that no longer exist, see Finding invalid objects.
>
> - The original permissions and extended properties of the object are preserved.

Answer (score 3):

There is a free tool you can use do do this,  ApexSQL Refactor.

After the tool is installed, Safe rename option will became available on right-click on selected object in SSMS Object explorer. After Safe rename window is opened, you can enter new name and click Rename.

Here is a video tutorial showing how to do this, which also explains some additional options:
https://tv.apexsql.com/apexsql-refactor-how-to-safely-rename-database-objects-without-breaking-dependencies/

Answer (score 1):

No - you will have to update all of the references to your table unfortunately.

Comment: It's a pity! But maybe is there a way to get all references on this table?

Comment: You can!  see my answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837191/sql-azure-schema-issue/42907085#42907085

Or search for something along the lines of 'find all references to table in objects sql server'

Answer (score 0):

Although the following procedure doesn't help you automatically rename all references, it can help find actual references and do safe refactoring.

If using any of the JetBrain's IDEs (like DataGrip, Rider or IntelliJ IDEA) in the Database explorer you can:

- Right click on the table (or view, column, etc.) and click on `Rename...` (or press `SHIFT + F6`)
- In the Rename dialog, turn on `Search in loaded resources` option
- Then click on `Preview` button

You will get the list of usages of the table/view you are re-naming and finally can do a refactor item by item from there.

Optionally, in the Rename dialog, you can also choose `Search for text occurrences` and `Search in comments and strings` to look for external references (outside the database) to the table/view in your source code (C#, Java, etc.)